# Cannot add my school provided google account in settings -> online accounts (403 Forbidden)

Tags: gnome, 22.04, settings, google, online-accounts

I am on Ubuntu 22.04,my personal google accounts gets added just fine, but when i try to add my school provided google account instead of opening my school's website where i log in it just says 403 forbidden error. I was able to add the account successfully in Ubuntu 23.04 and Fedora though.[error image] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e45oT.png)